# Polynomial linear transformations

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations

This is probably a simple question:

How does `f(x) = 3x` become `f(x+y) = 3(x+y)` in this example:

`f(x) = 3x => f(x+y) = 3(x+y) = 3x+3y = f(x) + f(y)`

Where does the y come from?

Thanks.

Comment: $x$ insiste the parentheses is a “dummy” variable. So you can replace it by anything such as $f(•)=3•$ or $f(PaulCrebs)=3PaulCrebs$. It just tells that $f$ takes anything as an argument and multiplies it by $3$. So if you “feed” $f$ with $x+y$ you get $3(x+y)$

Comment: Replace the symbol $x$ by $x+y$.

Comment: Makes kinda sense if it wasn't for the rest of the example: ```f(x) = 3x => f(x+y) = 3(x+y) = 3x+3y = f(x) + f(y) ```
If the variable x is just replaced with x+y, how then can we separate x and y towards the end? That wouldn't be possible if we had replaced x with 'PaulCrebs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! I understand how this could be confusing for a beginner. In this context, $f(x) = 3x$ *really means*
$$f(x) = 3x \text{ for all }x\in D$$
where $D$ is your domain of interest. In most cases, you'd be happy with $D = \mathbb R$, so let's use that. The reason why $\forall x\in D$ is *implicit* in such cases, is because $f(x) = x$ is the **function definition** with you. To define a function, you must know what values it takes on the entire domain!

If $x,y\in \Bbb R$, then $x+y\in\Bbb R$ too, and you can use your definition of $f$ to say that $$f: x+y\mapsto 3(x+y)\\ \text{i.e. } f(x+y) = 3(x+y) = 3x+3y$$
In fact, feel free to conclude things like $$f(x^2) = 3x^2, f(e^x) = 3e^x, f(\text{anything in the domain}) = 3(\text{anything in the domain})$$
given $f(x) = 3x$.

Comment: My goodness that makes so much more sense. Thank you so much!